# How to add multiple values under a single key in dictionary

Tags: vba

Code: VBA

How to do the following with the help of dictionary?

Item "Facebook" should have multiple keys, like

.Add Item "Facebook", "brand", 2

.Add Item "Facebook", "post", 5

.Add Item "Facebook", "likes", 7

And how to search for the integer value?

Comment: Dictionaries require a *unique* key. There are several ways to store data like that in a dictionary, but you're limited to key lookups on the unique identifier. How you structure your container depends mainly on how you intend to use it.  What does the rest of the code do?

Comment: Basically I want to store the positions of parameters(Likes, Comments, Shares, etc.) of various channels(Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, etc.) using dictionary. I have tried using arrays, but its a tedious work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using either a user type or a class for storing your data. For example:

```
'Minimalistic ChannelInfo.cls
Option Explicit

Public Channel As String
Public Category As String
Public Count As Integer
```

As for the container, a `Dictionary` requires a unique key, so another type of container (array, Collection, or custom container class) might be a better choice depending on how you'll be retrieving items from it. If you need to get a unique key for an arbitrary `Type`, you can use the `VarPtr`.  If you need a unique object key you can either create your own hash function or use use its `ObjPtr`.  Note that neither of these are particularly useful for retrieving items that you don't already have a reference to.

```
Dim myFoos As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim foo As ChannelInfo

Set foo = New ChannelInfo
With foo
    .Channel = "Facebook"
    .Category = "brand"
    .Count = 2
End With

myFoos.Add ObjPtr(foo), foo
```

If the combination of Channel and Category is what you are using to aggregate items later, it might be more useful to use that as a key:

```
'Key is "Facebook|brand"
myFoos.Add foo.Channel & "|" & foo.Category, foo
```

Comment: there seem to be some missing dots after `With foo`

Comment: IMO (:-)) for such a simple structure UDT would be preferable

Comment: @user3598756 - It might in an array, but it can be problematic with Collections and Dictionaries because it can run into [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361276/can-udts-be-used-as-method-parameters-in-any-way). I'd also actually develop the class a little bit (load and save methods, validation, etc).

Comment: that issue speaks about UDT in classes: does it apply for UDT in collections too? While should any method come in then there's no doubt class is the one

Comment: @user3598756 - The issue is related marshalling UDTs across class boundaries.  Passing a UDT to the `.Add` method requires that it be cast through a `Variant`, which requires typelib information to allow the marshaller to allocate memory for it (it would normally be passed as VT_USERDEFINED).  The compiler essentially freaks out because doesn't know how to cast.

Comment: so will a UDT in a `Collection` run into that issue for sure or it just _could_?

Comment: @user3598756 - Could.  But it's flaky enough that I try to avoid it - it can pop up seemingly randomly depending on the order of code changes and compilations.  It's easy to confuse the compiler when the "typelib" of the project doesn't match the compiled project stored in the document.

Comment: I see. So may be better take UDT off initial suggestion?

Comment: @user3598756 - Nah, they work fine in arrays because they're strongly typed - if the type is truly a simple type they might be the right solution in an array or custom container class that can strongly type them.

Comment: maybe it's my bad reading only, but your (fine) answer suggests both UDT and Class and when it comes to its possible _containers_ doesn't warn about possible issue of UDT coupled with Collections or Dictionaries.

Comment: @user3598756 - So don't up-vote it.  Down-vote it if you like.  The example has a class, and I think the comments more than suffice for the UDT v. class discussion at this point.

Comment: It was not a matter of voting. I think comments are a lower class of info with respect with the answer itself: if a relevant issue arises from them it'd be better trigger an answer update. Nothing more