# Object Variable not assigned

Tags: vba

Code:VBA

Having problems with making the items of dictionary as a variable.

```
Dim facebook As Object, instagram As Object, twitter As Object, name As Object
name = InputBox("Enter the name of the channel", "Channel")
Dim type_name As String
type_name = InputBox("Enter the type of value you want", "Type")

Set facebook = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With facebook

    .comparemode = vbTextCompare
    .Add "brand", 5
    .Add "post", 6
    .Add "likes", 7

End With

Set instagram = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With instagram

    .comparemode = vbTextCompare
    .Add "brand", 8
    .Add "post", 9
    .Add "likes", 10

End With

Set twitter = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With twitter

    .comparemode = vbTextCompare
    .Add "brand", 11
    .Add "post", 12
    .Add "likes", 13

End With

MsgBox (name & "." & type_name & "=" & name(type_name))
```

This code is giving an error "Object variable or With Block variable not set" after the inputbox which takes the value "name".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified a wrong type for `name` in the very first line of your script:

```
Dim facebook As Object, instagram As Object, twitter As Object, name As Object
```

It should be:

```
Dim facebook As Object, instagram As Object, twitter As Object, name As String
```

There is also an error in the last line of your script:

```
name(type_name)
```

You seem to expect that `name` is both a string and a dictionary object at the same time. For this kind of syntax you would need to create another dictionary object that has as keys "facebook", "instagram", "twitter" and returns as value for them the corresponding dictionary you already created. So you get a nested structure.

Here is the code:

```
Dim facebook As Object, instagram As Object, twitter As Object, channels as Object
Dim name As String, type_name As String

name = InputBox("Enter the name of the channel", "Channel")
type_name = InputBox("Enter the type of value you want", "Type")

Set facebook = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With facebook
    .comparemode = vbTextCompare
    .Add "brand", 5
    .Add "post", 6
    .Add "likes", 7
End With

Set instagram = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With instagram
    .comparemode = vbTextCompare
    .Add "brand", 8
    .Add "post", 9
    .Add "likes", 10
End With

Set twitter = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With twitter
    .comparemode = vbTextCompare
    .Add "brand", 11
    .Add "post", 12
    .Add "likes", 13
End With

Set channels = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With channels
    .comparemode = vbTextCompare
    .Add "facebook", facebook
    .Add "instagram", instagram
    .Add "twitter", twitter
End With

MsgBox (name & "." & type_name & "=" & channels(name)(type_name))
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked! but now another problem has come. In

MsgBox (name & "." & type_name & "=" & name(type_name))

It is giving an error, "Expected Array" and is highlighting "name" of "name(type_name)"

Comment: Indeed, like the error says, `name` is not an array. I don't understand what you expect that part to do.

Comment: I want "name" to store the value of the channel(say facebook) and "type_name" to store the value of type(say brand). then "name(type_name)" should display the item of that specific type in that channel.

Comment: you should follow what @Comintern told you in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181335/how-to-add-multiple-values-under-a-single-key-in-dictionary/39181821?noredirect=1#comment65707932_39181821)

Comment: I updated my answer to deal with that as well. Please, next time do not ask new questions in the comment area, but create a new question for them. ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it and I'll keep it in mind! Thank you again!

Comment: @VaibhavMiglani, Since this answer worked for you, please accept it by clicking the check mark next to the answer.